Inspecting payload to an outbound FTP adapter with MockIntegrationContext
I have a Spring Integration flow that looks like the following (simplified)
  @Bean
  public StandardIntegrationFlow integrationFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(inputChannel())
        .transform(transformer())
        .channel(outputChannel())
        .get();
  }

  @Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outputChannel")
  public MessageHandler ftpOutboundAdapter(DefaultFtpSessionFactory ftpSessionFactory) {
    return Ftp.outboundAdapter(ftpSessionFactory)
        .remoteDirectory("/remote-directory")
        .fileNameGenerator(message -> "output.txt")
        .get();
  }

In my test, I am directly sending a message to the flow's input channel and I want to capture the payload as it is coming out and be able to assert on its contents. I am doing it with MockIntegrationContext like this
    ArgumentCaptor<Message<?>> messageArgumentCaptor = messageArgumentCaptor();
    MessageHandler mockMessageHandler = mockMessageHandler(messageArgumentCaptor)
        .handleNext(m -> {});
    mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageHandlerFor("ftpOutboundAdapter", mockMessageHandler);

I am, however, getting the following error
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'ftpOutboundAdapter' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.integration.endpoint.IntegrationConsumer' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.integration.ftp.outbound.FtpMessageHandler' 
How do I get around this? Should I do the FTP outbound adapter differently? How do I properly substitute a mock handler for it? Is there an altogether better and easier way of doing this? Thanks.

You are on the right way to do such a verification in the test.
However the problem that substituteMessageHandlerFor is about an endpoint, not the handler by itself. That ftpOutboundAdapter method is a bean name exactly for the MessageHandler instance. The endpoint, built from that @ServiceActivator has different bean name. See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/overview.html#endpoint-bean-names
So, I think to fix your problem you would just need an @EndpointId("ftpOutboundEndpoint") and use that name in the substituteMessageHandlerFor() call.
